# A DataGrid with Text, Images and Buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I want to realise a Chat, where the people can send messages. 
Each message can contain one button where the other poeple can click at. Maybe I also want to display a avatar beside each message. I was looking for a build in component like List or DataGrid, but I didn't find the opportunity to add buttons or images. 
It should also be possible to resize the chat and to scroll through the messages. 
What do you think? Which is the best approach to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to be a little more specific...What technologies are you using other than your tagged stuff ?

Comment: I want to realize it in actionscript with flash professional in combination with flash builder. I dont no which other technologies do you mean? At the moment i do not use flex but i am open for everything.

Answer (score 0):

To add images/buttons to a `List` or `DataGrid`, you will need to create a custom `ItemRenderer` (for `List`) or `GridColumnItemRenderer` (for `Grid`). You can read about this [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_2.html) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html#WS5ED0A932-BA59-4a77-9A9D-3745FE21D1E9)